# SQL Server 2008 R2 grant permission to access file system via SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

How can a user be granted permission to access a sever's file system via SSMS using SQL Server authentication without making them a member of the sysadmin role?

I'd like to use SSMS to perform tasks such as restoring and creating new db's on a remote installation of SQL Server, which requires me to access the server's file system.  The only way I've been able to access the file system so far has been to grant sysadmin to my user.  Although we're working in development now, the installation's owner will not grant sysadmin to my production user.  Is there another way?

Comment: To create, drop, or restore a database, the sql login must be a member of fixed server role `dbcreator` or `sysadmin`.  That covers the permissions aspect from the SQL Server point of view.  From the Windows point of view, if you are restoring a db from backup file(s) that are on the host SQL server, file system permissions are probably not going to be an issue.  If the backup file(s) reside elsewhere (ie a UNC path) the windows login of the *SQL Server service* must have appropriate permissions to access the UNC path.

Comment: Thanks for the response DMason.  However, after adding every server role (including dbcreator) except sysadmin, I still couldn't access the file system.  Only sysadmin seems to do the trick.  Because the sysadmin role allows access to the file system, it leads me to believe that the issue is related to SQL server permissions - not Windows permissions.

Comment: Something doesn't add up. Can you post the error message you are getting?